# Reading plist file at specific index

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I have to save some 100 sentences in my app. Each sentence is around 50-90 characters. I can create a .plist file for this. But i dont want to read the whole .plist file, just want to read a specific index. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no API for reading plist files partially. For 10kB files that's not much of a problem, just read it and discard what you don't need.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether it's possible to avoid reading whole file. But if you want to access a single entry then you can create an array from plist and access the index (i assume that you are already aware of this). It won't take much memory unless your app is already heavy loaded.